# Typescript combine generic objects type

Tags: typescript

I'm using a React module which has a declared type like this,

```
export declare type SomeContainer = React.FunctionComponent<{
    prop1: string
    prop2: number
    prop3: () => void
}>
```

I would like to add to this an internal type,

```
type Container = React.FunctionComponent<{
    prop4: string
}>
```

So the desired type would look like this if written without the module,

```
type DesiredContainer = React.FunctionComponent<{
    prop1: string
    prop2: number
    prop3: () => void
    prop4: string
}>
```

So I tried to combine them like,

```
type Combined = SomeContainer & Container
```

But the problem is when I use this new type for my function component,

```
const Component: Combined = props => {
```

I get the error `Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any'`, and none of the properties can be used on the `props` variable.

Is there a way to combine these types to achieve what I want, or will I have to internally declare the modules type with my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the type information of the argument which is passed to the `Container` function:

```
type SomeContainerArgType = SomeContainer extends (arg1: infer U) => any ? U : any;
```

And then:

```
type MyType = SomeContainerArgType & {
    prop4: string;
};

type DesiredContainer = React.FunctionComponent<MyType>;
```